# How to bring my focus back on technical work?

Tags: career-development

I was a professional programmer for about 10 years. I was doing pretty well in my job till I got promotion 2 years ago. As my new role, I was supposed to do "people-management-cum-technical-lead" for a team having 10+ members.

I had never done any people management or technical leadership roles earlier, neither I got any training or time to prepare for it. My boss got sacked and I was literally put on his role suddenly.

It's been 2 years since then and I feel really trapped. I am not a great people manager as I keep to myself. I enjoy doing a lot of techie stuff but hardly get any time for it due to so many admin-type of tasks. I only get to do some code-review and that too in varied technologies.

With the lapse of time, I feel I am getting out-dated and am losing confidence in coding even simple things or discussing technical stuff.

Could you please suggest some ways to bring back my focus and confidence on technical stuff?

Comment: Hi and welcome to [workplace.se]. Currently I'm a bit confused by what you want us to help you with? Are you looking for ways to get back to your old role and leave management functions behind? Or would you rather we suggest resources for you to learn or practice in your free time, to give you more confidence in your technical skills?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I guess the first question you need to ask yourself is what path you want to take going forward.  If you want to keep in management then I suggest that all you really need to do at this point is some light reading each week to see how things are trending.

However, if you want to just go back to programming then you need to discuss this with your current manager.  Let them know that you want to "step down" from management and get back into just programming.  Provided they have an open dev position they should be amenable to this.  If they aren't then you need to locate a new job.

The third option is just keep doing what you are and, on your own time, locate an open source project that you can contribute to.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. I'd add: and be quick about relocating if that is what you decide on to get back to programming. If you don't want to stay in managing, then every month you do stay will make it harder to switch.

Comment: +1 for contributing to an open-source project. There's a lot to learn and a lot of people to work with. It's a great path to go down!

Comment: If your company has a "guru" track for senior technical expertise, it doesn't have to be a "step down" either.  More of a lateral movement.